# Plane is backward on right Orthographic view

Tags: uv

I keep rotation it but my place is alway backward on Right O view. It is front on the left and I do not know how to fix this... I am using blender 2.8 [image]

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> to show **Left** orthographic view.

Likewise you can access **Bottom** view by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>

For **Back** view press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>

Comment: I need to flip the plane around not the view point. I already know how to get to the different view points, that is how I know the front side is on the left orthographic view. I need plane front side to be on the right side like in this video  :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvZfYwp8n9Q

Comment: Rotate the plane 180 degrees in the Z axis... (press RZ180)

Comment: at x = 90 Y = 0 and z = 180.. you can not see it on the  Left orthographic Nor the Right  orthographic view at x = 90 y = 0 z = 90, you get the picture I posted with it being backwards on the right orthographic view

Comment: ok I close blender and  reopening it and it just started working right ... there are so many bugs with this programs. I find that closing and reopening it fixes a lot of things... The thing is I am new to blender so I do not know if it is something I am doing wrong or a bug...